# Get address on click Google Map using gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using rails 3.2.3 and gmaps4rails gem.

I have one model called contact. In the contact object I have one filed named address.

Now I have defined the contact as acts_as_gmappable and gmaps4rails_address takes the address field to show as a marker in the google map.

Now, while we add new contact, I want to add a feature such that the address will be auto filled when we click on the google map with the clicked location.

How can I do that with the help of gmaps4rails gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good guide on the wiki that might help. Look for the section "Drop a marker and update fields attribute in a form"

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies

Simply include the javascript, and update the following with your actual field IDs (you might want some hidden :lat :lon fields on your form)

```
$('#location_attributes_latitude').val(latLng.lat());
$('#location_attributes_longitude').val(latLng.lng());
$('#location_attributes_gmaps_zoom').val(Gmaps.map.serviceObject.getZoom());
```

On save, you'll need to check whether the user has entered an address manually, or used the map.

If they've used the map, you'll need a method to reverse geocode and fetch an address from Google using the :lat :lon values.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3.2 with erb, to add an id you should do like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:latitudex, "", :id => "location_attributes_latitude") %>
```

Thanks for the answer, the "field IDs" is what I was missing.